# A/B Testing Emails - Adding another utm- variable

Tags: email, google-analytics, ab-testing

I run a script on a local computer which sends out "review request emails" to customers who bought an item from a particular website. I have the website linked up to analytics so I can see how effective the emails are, and I make each link on the email with the correct google-analytics utm_ variables, like so:

`www.website.com?utm_source=mailjet&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=review_request`

So I was trying to figure out if there's an additional variable I could add to the URL to distinguish between two different types of Review Request emails I send, to see which is more effective.

I've read that using `utm_content` might be the variable I'm looking for, but I'm not sure I'd be using it correctly or that's the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utm_content` would work fine for you. just add this alongside the other utm parameters and set the distinctive value for each variation, e.g.:

```
www.website.com?utm_source=mailjet&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=review_request&utm_content=red_variant
```

Then the *Ad Content* dimension in your GA reports will reflect the actual values of `utm_content` and you'll be able to use is as a primary or secondary dimension

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I'll get a chance to put this into practice within the next week.